# Azure DevOps Deployment : E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, post-build-event, post-build

I need to install a pre-built environment for my application to be deployed, with a bash script that i add to parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel
```

I got the permission error, so I tried this as suggested

```
#!/bin/bash
killall apt apt-get
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel
```

The problem is that i can't use sudo (sudo doesn't work on azure), how to manage this and force the postbuild installation without sudo

(I have tried to add exec, but it said : it can only be used by a terminal).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is working on my side on DevOps pipeline.

Add `sudo` in my bash script:
[image]

My yaml:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: 'install.sh'
```

Pipeline result:
[image]

If the issue persists for you, please elaborate a bit for your agent info(Microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted), error screenshot, log...etc. What azure cloud you mean if it's not DevOps.

Comment: Hi @Moun, how is it going? Is there any update?

Comment: I found this thread with outlines more-or-less the same solution as the above: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/apt-get-install-failed-to-start-due-to-dpkg-lock-f/1062860